# Assign turtle variables from csv in Netlogo

Tags: csv, netlogo

I want turtles to read and adopt data from csv file.  I have written the following code: the problem is even-though the data gets loaded, i'm unable to make the individual turtles take on each of the income values. Any assistance to this effect would be appreciated

```
extensions [csv]
breed [households household]
households-own [income]
globals [income-data]

to setup
  load-income-data
  setup-households
end

to load-income-data
  set income-data []
  file-open "income.csv"
  while [ not file-at-end? ]
  [ set income-data sentence income-data ( file-read-line)
  ]
  user-message "income data loading complete!"
  file-close
end

to setup-households
  create-households 700
  ask one-of households
  [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set income income-data
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the File Input Example in the NetLogo Model Library (Code Examples). You need to use a foreach to loop through the imported values / agents.